# Is decision tree regression comparable to locally weighted regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am new to decision tree method. For decision tree regression model, does it just fit a piece wise step function over data? When and why would people prefer it over some traditional regression like locally weighted (LOESS) regression?
(Cross asked at [Data Science stack exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24138/is-decision-tree-regression-comparable-to-locally-weighted-regression))

Answer (score 2):

> For decision tree regression model, does it just fit a piece wise step function over data?

Yes.

> When and why would people prefer it over some traditional regression like locally weighted (LOESS) regression?

These models have the same strengths/weaknesses as $k$-NN strategies: yeah, you can strongly localize behavior, but prediction requires a lot of computation and doesn't scale well.